# Meaning of Imported New Chain Segment

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, blocks

This is not a troubleshooting question, I'm not having problems with geth or the blockchain sync, but I'm curious about the meaning of a text that appears at the end:

**Imported new chain segment.**

I have seen troubleshooting answers mentioning that text but no one explains what it means. It has been explained in other answers the text: "Imported new state entries". But never this one. Can someone explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Imported new chain segment" just means that geth has downloaded some amount of blocks to be added to the chain.

Comment: I get this in my private network where I have only one peer. How could a new block be added automatically?

Comment: I have the same question that I just start my Ethereum nodes in my private network and did nothing to them. I didn’t add any transaction to the blockchain. However, “Imported new chain segment” message were keeping showing.